# Is the inverse of a function a functional?

Tags: functions, inverse-function

We know functionals are mappings from a function to a variable. So does it matter if the output variable is just the independent variable of the function? I.e. is the inverse of a function a functional?

Comment: a functional typically maps a function to a single number, such as $G(f)=\int_0^1f(x) dx$. But if a function is not one-to-one,  then even if evaluated at a single point its inverse may not be a single number.

Comment: [1] In general , Inverse of a function $y=f(x)$ is a function $x=f^{-1}(y)$ , Eg $\sin()$ & $\sin^{-1}()$. [2] A functional converts a function to a Single Number. In general , we can not convert that Single Number back to that function. In other words , a functional may have no Inverse.